# solving a derivative more elegantly

Tags: calculus

$$f(x)=\frac {(x^2+4x+13)(x-2)^2}{(x^2+3x+3)(x+1)^4}$$
find $$\frac {df(x)}{dx}$$

I tried to transform the equation into

$$f(x)=\frac {2(x^2+4x+13)\ln(x-2)}{4(x^2+3x+3)\ln(x+1)}$$

but still taking a lot of steps to derive it, is there any faster approach solving this?

Comment: We can note that $x^2+3x+3=(x+1)(x+2)$, and perform the coordinate transformation $x=u-1$, giving us $\frac{(u^2+2u+8)(u-3)^2}{(u+1)u^5}$ to solve, which definitely looks simpler to me.

Comment: If you take the log of both sides, you will get $$\log f = \log(x^2 + 4x + 13) + 2\log (x-2)-\log(x^2+3x+3) - 4\log (x+1)$$ then differentiating you get $$\frac{f'}{f} = \frac{2x+4}{x^2+4x+13} + \frac{2}{x-2}-\frac{2x+3}{x^2+3x+3} - \frac{4}{x+1}$$ and can find $f'$ by multiplying both sides by $f$. Is that what you are after?

Comment: The correct term isn't "solve." We compute, evaluate, or determine a derivative, but we never "solve a derivative."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking logs makes it much easier: if $f=f_1f_2f_3\dotsm f_n$, then 
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\log{f} = \frac{f'}{f} = \frac{d}{dx} \left( \log{f_1} + \log{f_2} + \dotsb \log{f_n} \right) = \frac{f_1'}{f_1}+ \frac{f_2'}{f_2} + \dotsb \frac{f_n'}{f_n}, $$
and then you can find $f'$ by multiplying both sides by $f$. In this case,
$$ \frac{f'}{f} = \frac{2x+4}{x^2+4x+13} +\frac{2}{x-2} - \frac{2x+3}{x^2+3x+3} - \frac{4}{x+1}, $$
and then you can multiply up easily enough. Depending on what you want the derivative for, you may need to still do some algebra on it.